# young age, youthful age?

Tags: word-choice

It would be great if you could help me phrase this sentence:

Many primary schools students also fail to recognise the importance of consuming breakfast due to **their age** .

Any suggestions for the replacement of "age" are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Try **"youth."** (Though based on my experience with 20-somethings, I'd question whether youth is the primary cause of this misunderstanding.)

Comment: Your parenthesized comment isn't relevant (except as a demo that the sentence is badly written) because “due to their age” is an explanation of why breakfast is important rather than an explanation of why the students don't see the importance of it.